# Icons in the overview search/show applications view appear vertically stretched, out of their containers

Tags: gnome, icons

In ubuntu 20.04, the icons seem to be vertically stretched out of their containers.

Screenshot
[image]

I've tried disabling all gnome extensions, but this still happens. I've also tried wayland and X11. Is there maybe an issue with scaling or resolution? Everything else seems to look just fine.

Thanks!

Comment: The screenshot you show is *with* extensions? Temporarily create a new user and see if the issue persists when you are in the new account: then you can tell whether this is a system wide issue or only caused by the user configuration.

Comment: Thanks, I've checked this with a new user account but the issue seems to persist (I've edited the post with a new screenshot). I also tried various display scaling factors and resolutions, which actually just made the icon distortion worse.

Answer (score 0):

This error is mostly caused by external gnome-shell themes which somehow don't get properly uninstalled at times.

I had the exact same problem while trying to uninstall yaru-colors however reinstalling the default yaru packages and restarting the gnome-shell fixed it for me

`sudo apt install --reinstall yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-gnome-shell`

then press Fn+Alt+F2 and input `r` then click enter (this will restart the gnome-shell)